# Text is not centered in modified button

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, text, fonts

None of the previous solutions seem to be working. I have some heavily modified buttons that look like this:
[image]

And, as you can see, the text is too high in the button. It needs to be lowered. Changing the margin doesn't work. Can't find anything that will adjust where the type appears in the button. Here's the XAML:

```
     <Button Grid.Row="0" x:Name="LaunchArmyEditor"  Content="Run the General Staff Army Editor" Height="86" Width="600" Click="LaunchArmyEditor_Click" FontFamily="Amaltea WF" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold"  Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,-1,0,0"  >
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="TransVictorianButton.png" Stretch="None"/>
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>

                <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LaunchMapEditor"   Content="Run the General Staff Map Editor" Height="86" Width="600" Click="LaunchMapEditor_Click" FontFamily="Amaltea WF" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold"  Cursor="Hand" >
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="TransVictorianButton.png" Stretch="None"/>
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try setting `Padding` property?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's under Layout, not Text so I didn't think of it.

Comment: You should be using a re-usable style and template rather than almost the same markup over and over. The problem will likely be the font. Those walden fonts don't measure properly. As to how to fix this. When you set the content of a button (or label) to a string, there is code in the control which inserts a textblock in the control and binds it's text to the content property. You therefore have a textblock is the content of your button and you can apply styling to that using resources of your button.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button's content be a label/textbox, instead of an attribute. Then adjust control being used accordingly such as using `Margin` property as shown below:

```
<Button … >
    <ContentControl>
        <Label Content="Run the General Staff Map Editor" Margin="0,4,0,0"/>
    </ContentControl>
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="TransVictorianButton.png" Stretch="None"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```